Excel - Highlight Row of Selected cell
I want to highlight the row of the selected cell in any active workbook. How can I achieve my goal?
I have experiences in highlighting selected row by using conditional formatting and change event. In conditional formatting I entered the formula row()=cell("row") in each worksheet and in the VBA in ThisWorkbook, I selected SheetSelectionChange and type in Application.ScreenUpdating=True
However, using the above method I need to setup conditional formatting and change event trigger in every single workbook. I would like to default this to active workbook/worksheet, .
Any ideas how to achieve my goal?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
